# What is the meaning of "..::." in C#?

Tags: c#

I saw this signature on the ListView class:

```
public ListView..::.ListViewItemCollection Items { get; }
```

When I saw that, "What?!"

I searched "dot dot colon colon dot" and "..::." on Google with no result.

[image]

Comment: Does it compile? The :: operator is the namespace alias operator, but the dots? I have no idea ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not C#; that's JScript. In C#, it would be:

```
public ListView.ListViewItemCollection Items { get; }
```

It's a little different because `ListViewItemCollection` is an inner class of `ListView`.

I'm guessing that you saw this looking at [ListView.Items Property (System.Windows.Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx).

If you look at the listing for all the other languages, they're all listed with the JScript syntax. You've found a documentation bug.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the ListView.Items property. I suspected it was a bug, but when I saw the Columns property it was listed as "..::." too. Seems that the documentation generator has a bug :D
Thank you!

Answer (score -4):

ListViewItemCollection is a nested type of ListView, which means that in the code, the Collection class is defined inside of the ListView definition, like so:

```
public class ListView {
  public ListViewItemCollection Items {get;}

  public class ListViewItemCollection : IList {
    // more code here
  }
}
```

I would assume that it is coded this way just to keep their source tree a little bit cleaner. This way, all of the helper collection classes that are associated with the ListView control aren't scattered throughout the directory. Inner classes do have a few special characteristics, but none that I can imagine would apply here.